# What does it mean for “1^n”(i.e., the security parameter written in unary)?

Tags: key-generation, notation

As it is mentioned above, I am confused about “Gen takes as input $1^n$ and outputs a key“. Does it mean that the input of Gen is 1111....111 with length of n?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [What exactly is a “security parameter”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52309/18298)